Adding total rows, calculated rows to sets and Pivot tables
I have two pivot tables - here is pivot table 1



Monthly Transfers by Item
Sum of 10-24 Item #
Sum of 9-24 Item #




Item 1
94
113


Item 2
17
22


Item 3
1



Item 4

1


Item 5
2
3


Item 6
1
1


Item 7
2
3


Item 8
3
4


Item 9
2
7


Item 10
35
46


Item 11
2
10


Item 12
1



Grand Total
160
210



And pivot table 2



Item 2, 4, 11
Sum of 10-24 Item #
Sum of 9-24 Item #




Item 2
17
22


Item 4

1


Item 11
2
10



I make Pivot table 2 as a set of pivot table 1 - I copy/paste pivot table 1 - go to Pivot Table Analyze - Calculations - Fields, Items & Sets - Create set based on row items
What I want to do is to add a total to the bottom of pivot table set that would read 19 and 33 for october and september numbers respectively. Then I would like to add this number to the bottom of pivot table 1, and then add another row where I get the net (grand total minus the three items)
Were I doing this with formulas it would be nested a cell or a table reference - such as sum(CHOOSECOLS(pivot table2, row #), but I'd like to build the calculations directly into the pivot table if possible.
I've gone to

design-layout-subtotals; doesn't seem to work
I've tried making a flattened pivot table in power pivot, doesn't seem to go further than
Can't seem to find any settings - adding a calculated field to the pivot table 2 (which is just the set of pivot table 1)

